# CSV File with minus sign after number. "ValueError: could not convert string to float:"

Tags: python, pandas, csv, valueerror

I have several CSV Files, where the a negative number is displayed with the minus sign after the number (30.50- instead of -30.50). If I try to convert the column to an integer, Python returns an ValueError (`ValueError: could not convert string to float: '30.50-'`)

Does anybody have an idea how to handle that?

Thanks in Advance!

Best,
Moritz

Comment: Please share a sample input with expected output.

Comment: because `30.50- ` is not a valid number, what are you expecting this to return? you might have to strip the `-` from right and handle it seperately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
In [141]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['30.50-', '20', '-10.01','22.10-']})
In [142]: df 
Out[142]: 
        A
0  30.50-
1      20
2  -10.01
3  22.10-

In [143]: df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: '-'+ (x.rstrip('-')) if x.endswith('-') else x).astype(float) 

In [145]: df 
Out[145]: 
       A
0 -30.50
1  20.00
2 -10.01
3 -22.10

In [144]: df.dtypes 
Out[144]: 
A    float64
dtype: object
```

Comment: it worked perfectly for the first couple CSVs, but for one I get the following error message: "TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable" even though the column is of the type Pandas type "object". The Error appears when the values suddenly don't have a decimal Point anymore ("1.000" is now a "1"). Do you have any idea how to handle that?

Answer (score 1):

As your `string` is not in valid format to convert into `float` you first need to make it right by remove `-` from right using [`rstrip`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.rstrip.html#pandas-series-str-rstrip) and add it to front.
For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':['1.5-','1.7','2.0','4.1-']})
df.a.apply(lambda x: '-'+(x.rstrip('-')) if x[-1] =='-' else x).astype(float)
0   -1.5
1    1.7
2    2.0
3   -4.1
Name: a, dtype: float64
```